# Revoke JWT using C#

Tags: c#, jwt

I have a custom `Authorize` class that I use to invalidate the token when user requests data or anything from the server

but whenever the token expires the principle still returns `IsAuthenticated` as true and still calls the controllers and get data.

What I want it to do is to invalidate the token and explicitly logout the user out of the system. I couldn't find anything helpful. I can provide code of the JWT attribute/filters if needed

Update 1: Token Generation

```
public static string GenerateToken(User user)
{
    int expireMinutes;
    try
    {
        expireMinutes = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SessionTimeInMinutes"])
            ? 30
            : int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SessionTimeInMinutes"]);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        expireMinutes = 30;
    }
    var symmetricKey = Convert.FromBase64String(Secret);
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email)
            ,new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName)
            ,new Claim("uid", user.Id.ToString())
            ,new Claim("cid", user.ClientId.ToString())
            ,new Claim("rid", string.Join(",", user.Roles.Select(r => r.RoleId).ToList()))
        }),
        Expires = now.AddMinutes(Convert.ToInt32(expireMinutes)),
        IssuedAt = now,
        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(symmetricKey), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
    };
    var stoken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
    var token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(stoken);
    return token;
}
```

Server side Authorization Token

```
 public async Task AuthenticateAsync(
        HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var excludedList = new List<string>();
        excludedList.Add("/api/Security/IsMustChangePassword");
        excludedList.Add("/api/Security/IsTwoFactorEnabled");

        if (!excludedList.Contains(context.ActionContext.Request.RequestUri.LocalPath))
        {
            var request = context.Request;
            var authorization = request.Headers.Authorization;
            if (authorization == null || authorization.Scheme != "Token")
            {
                return;
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(authorization.Parameter))
            {
                context.ErrorResult = new AuthenticationFailureResult("Missing Jwt Token", request);
                return;
            }

            //{
            //    context.ErrorResult = new AuthenticationFailureResult("Invalid token", request);
            //    return;
            //}
            var token = authorization.Parameter;
            var principal = await AuthenticateJwtToken(token).ConfigureAwait(true);
            var userId = int.Parse(new JwtManager().GetUserIdFromToken(token));
            var accountManager = new AccountManager();
            var user = accountManager.GetUserDetails(userId);
            var newToken = JwtManager.GenerateToken(user);

            if (principal == null)
                context.ErrorResult = new AuthenticationFailureResult("Invalid token", request);
            else
                context.Principal = principal;

            if (principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var expiryDate = JwtManager.GetSecurityToken(token).ValidTo.ToLocalTime();
                if ((DateTime.Now - expiryDate).TotalSeconds > 0)
                {
                    context.Request.Headers.Authorization = null;
                    context.Request.RequestUri = null;


                }
                else
                {
                    var authorize = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("token", newToken);
                    context.Request.Headers.Authorization = authorize;
                    context.ActionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization = authorization;
                }
            }



        }

    }

    private static bool ValidateToken(string token, out string username, out 
    string passwordHash)
    {
        username = null;
        passwordHash = null;
        try
        {
            var principle = JwtManager.GetPrincipal(token);
            var identity = principle.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

            if (identity == null)
                return false;

            if (!identity.IsAuthenticated)
                return false;

            var usernameClaim = identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name);
            var passwordClaim = identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Hash);

            username = usernameClaim?.Value;
            passwordHash = passwordClaim?.Value;

            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(username);

            var user = identity.FindFirst(username);
            return (user != null);
            //return (user != null && user.PasswordHash == passwordHash);
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    protected Task<IPrincipal> AuthenticateJwtToken(string token)
    {
        string username;
        string passwordHash;
        if (!ValidateToken(token, out username, out passwordHash))
            return Task.FromResult<IPrincipal>(null);
        // based on username to get more information from database in order to build local identity
        var claims = new List<Claim> { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username) };
        //claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Hash, passwordHash));
        // Add more claims if needed: Roles, ...

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Jwt");
        IPrincipal user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        return Task.FromResult(user);
    }

    public Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var authorization = context.Request.Headers.Authorization;
        var excludedList =
            new List<string> {
                "/api/Security/IsMustChangePassword",
                "/api/Security/IsTwoFactorEnabled" };
        if (context.Request.Headers.Authorization != null)
        {
            if (!excludedList.Contains(context.ActionContext.Request.RequestUri.LocalPath))
            {
                var token = context.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter;
                var userId = int.Parse(new JwtManager().GetUserIdFromToken(token));
                var accountManager = new AccountManager();
                var user = accountManager.GetUserDetails(userId);
                var newToken = JwtManager.GenerateToken(user);
                var expiryDate = JwtManager.GetSecurityToken(token).ValidTo.ToLocalTime();
                if ((DateTime.Now - expiryDate).TotalSeconds > 0)
                {

                    context.Request.Headers.Authorization = null;
                    context.Request.RequestUri = null;
                    context.Request.RequestUri = new Uri("/Login");
                }
                else
                {
                    var authorize = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("token", newToken);
                    context.Request.Headers.Authorization = authorize;
                    context.ActionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization = authorization;
                }
                Challenge(context);

            }
        }
        else
        {
            var req = context.Request.RequestUri;
            var url = context.Request.RequestUri = new Uri($"http://{req.Host}:{req.Port}/api/Security/login");
            context.Request.RequestUri = url;
            context.Request.Headers.Authorization = null;
            context.Result= new AuthenticationFailureResult(string.Empty, new HttpRequestMessage());
        }


        return Task.FromResult(0);

    }
```

Comment: It depends on how you're *issuing* the JWT.  Show us your code, please.

Comment: If an expired token is somehow gaining access to your web services, then your code has some problem in its logic.  The only real engineering challenge with logout happens when a user logs out _before_ his JWT expires.  Then, you usually need to resort to some sort of blacklist to revoke the JWT which is technically still valid.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen so I'm supposed to store the blacklisted tokens in db to know who is authenticated and who isn't?

Comment: No, that's not what I said.  To add to what I said above: For every request, first, you should check the expiry claims (standard name is `exp`) to see if the incoming JWT be expired.  If it is expired, then categorically reject the request.  But, even if it's valid, you should check against a blacklist, usually in a cache somewhere.

Comment: The edge case here is that someone could logout _before_ his JWT expires.  Then, you have a user with a rogue JWT which he himself has invalidated.  Well, you have to also invalidate that JWT logically on your end.  A blacklist is a typical way to do this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I somehow handled the expired part using the custom Authorize annotation yet the requests still get data for expired tokens instead of returning not authorized.

Comment: "I have a custom Authorize class that I use to invalidate the token when user requests data or anything from the server" I don't see anything like that in your code. Seems you did not post the most important piece?

Comment: @nvoigt added please check

Comment: I still don't see where you invalidate the old token. Can you point out were you invalidate the token?

Comment: @nvoigt at the very end when setting context.Request.Headers.Authorization = null

Comment: That's not invalidating anything. The client still has the JWT and it's still valid. You just removed it from the request.

Comment: @nvoigt yes but if you checked there's an if condition that checks the validTo time of the token, if it's removed it shouldn't go to the controller if I'm not mistaken and if yes I do remove it from the request how do I stop it from going to the controllers?

Comment: Your usage of JWT is quite strange... a JWT *is* the authentication, you don't need to log in with data from the token. Security-wise, I'd say it's dangerous to actually have that information in there. As for your question... did you use a debuggger and step through it?

Comment: @nvoigt Yes I did, as per the project that's how the token was written at the first place, I'm supposed to maintain a session for the token and so on. Anyhow I think I was able to handle the validity of the token, now keeping the token alive is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: A JWT is just a client-token the client can manipulate. There is no absolute security here. The JWT is secured by the symmetirc key but cannot be invalidated itself. A valid token remains valid until it expires. It's a flaw of JWT (as @TimBiegeleisen pointed out in the comments) that a token itself cannot be easily invalidated.

If a user works too long and gets logged out automatically, your JWT has expired and everthing's good. There's no hassle as it runs out naturally and you have no need to act.

To invalidate a token you need to create a new token with `Expires = now.AddMinutes(-1)`. That way the next time you check the JWT next time you see it has expired.

The case that a user may save a JWT and use it even after being logged out can only be come by with blacklisting JWTs or maintaining some other kind of serverside session aditionally (which doesn't work i.e. with a stateless webservice).

**EDIT:** Removed wrong information and added a additional way to invalidate a JWT(blacklisting)

Comment: you made that clear, so I'm going to try your answer and see what's gonna happen.

Thank you!

Comment: @MohamedHesham You're welcome. If you have any questions, dont hesitate to ask them here (as long as they are no duplicate) and we'll answer :). That's what StackOverflow is for

Comment: I rarely downvote answers, but I did in this case because you said something incorrect: `A JWT is just a client-token the client can manipulate` ... JWTs are signed and generally _cannot_ be tampered with by the client.  If they _could_ be tampered with, then the entire pattern would fail.

Comment: If an incoming JWT bears valid claims, including most of all an `exp` expiry claim which is still valid, then the server should _not_ need to fall back to an additional authentication, except possibly to hit a cache to check if that JWT is blacklisted.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen And in the case I save the value of my JWT and reuse it after I logged out? Then I have a valid JWT again. Do I really need to blacklist all tokens that were invalidated before their normal expiration?

Comment: Yes, unless you want to still allow them to be used.  This is an inherent flaw in the JWT pattern.  Because such JWT have already been issued, then really isn't any other way to handle this problem.  By the way, if you change your language, then I am happy to upvote your answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm trying not be rude, I apologize if that's been the case. I'll adjust my answer as I used wrong information here. Can you please point out what you mean with "change your language"?

Comment: OK...maybe you are thinking of a different setup with JWT here.  It seems you are suggesting that the server maintains a session, when in fact one of the whole points of using JWT is that the server can be (almost) completely stateless.  That is, the session itself lives inside the JWT on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply cash a the token you want to revoke
and then make your authentication part compare request that has the revoked
with the one in the cash and refuse the request based on that

until the token expires , the cash should know the remining time for the token and cash it for that long